# Is ubuntu trying to update BIOS secure boot keys?

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, secure-boot

This question is related to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/239523/investigating-hp-sure-start-triggering-security-warnings/239635#239635) and [this](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Unauthorized-change-to-the-secure-boot-keys-amp-cannot/m-p/7808390) posts.

I have a HP elitebook 840 g3 running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. After one of the last system & zoom upgrades, I started receiving this BIOS message each time I boot the machine

> "HP Sure Start detected an unauthorized change to the Secure Boot
> Keys. The key was restored automatically and there is no further
> action required. The repeated occurrence of this problem indicates a
> security problem should not be ignored."

I was advised to ask here how could I determine if Ubuntu is trying to mess with the keys? That is

> Is there a way to see if an application on Ubuntu is trying to change the Secure Boot keys? If so, how?

Comment: Try this command ```journalctl -xe | grep -i -e keys -e boot```

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen The boot keyword is not found, https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ptwgPfRRS7/ would that imply ubuntu is not touching the boot keys?

Comment: Try this command ```grep -i -a -e key -e boot <<< cat auth.log```